# Can shoes mask injuries or weaknesses?

Tags: injury, running-shoes, stability

A little background: I got a gait analysis from a major sports therapy hospital, and she said I overpronate and suggested me some stability shoes. I also have a weak IT band, which I'm currently doing exercises to improve.

I just bought a new pair of running shoes, and my legs are feeling tender. It seems that each time I buy new shoes, my legs start to hurt again, injuries I'm sure are related to my IT band issue.

Is it possible that my old running shoes were masking certain weaknesses that these new shoes are highlighting? Or is it just my legs getting used to a different pair of shoes?

Comment: Where does it hurt, more specifically?

Comment: I would be inclined to say that it's most likely just adjustment.

Comment: @Marten The sides of my knees and deep in my hip joints.

Answer (score 3):

I am a veteran runner (and I have also suffered ITBS when I began to run). Even worse, I have what's called "Morton's Toe" so that I am not even supposed to be running according to orthopaedics and podiatrists

I am very sceptic in regard to stability additions to shoes for beginners and gait analysis.

The reasons for that is common sense:

When you start running your muscles are not yet adapted to the type of motion of the sport, specially legs and feet but all your muscles in general.

When you train your muscles and tendons will change and with that your gait. Not only that: Your gait and even the shape of you feet will change *during a run*.

Thus, if you correct the gait that you had when starting to run on a treadmill even if it is beneficial in the beginning there will be a point during your run where the limitations that the correction impose will not fit your actual needs.

The only real way to address your gait and ITBS issues is working on your running form, this means running and strengthening your core, butt and legs: Do bridges, planks, lateral planks, side leg raises or if you have the time and opportunity engage in Pilates and search a good running coach.

You can add a very good short drill for running form: On a soft surface (not sand) take out your shoes and run 10 yards at an easy leisurely pace with your hands hanging at your side, don't sprint, just imagine you are a child playing and concentrate on the way it feels, the way your feet touch the ground. Repeat this routine for 10 minutes or so running to one side and back resting as long as you feel.

Once you have mastered that rise your hands at our sides to a point between your hips and you chest and swing them while running avoiding that to cross them over your body, how much angle you use and how you swing them is up to you but don't cross them past the centre of our body.

And last but not least: Do small steps. The key to good and injury free running is high cadence rather than long strides, thus in the beginning use small steps, you will be able to increase your stride length with time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've also been running for several years, but I increased my distance a couple years ago which is when my IT band troubles started. Personally, the stability shoes have done nothing but improve my running and reduce my pain. I appreciate your comments, though.